# Definition of the anticanonical bundle and references

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

I am looking for the definition of the anticanonical bundle of an algebraic variety. In the books, I only find the definition of the canonical bundle.

Question 1 : Could anyone write me this definition? It would help me a lot.

Question 2 : Do you have any reference about the bundles, the divisors, and the relationship between them, to advise? If possible not too abstract. For example, I really like the notes of Gathmann about Algebraic Geometry.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The anticanonical bundle is just the dual of the canonical bundle. Any introductory algebraic geometry book will have material about line bundles and divisors - Vakil, Hartshorne, Gortz & Wedhorn, etc etc etc.